# Cant see any changes on browser when modify code YII

Tags: php, apache, yii

Hi I have got project where I have to do some changes, but then I do some changes in php files I can't see any changes in web browser, only then I deleted files, when I see error in windows, but if I comment all lines from same file, and want see changes, when I refreshed the page where will be page like before, what means I see  page like normally, and if I download the file and open it I see commented lines.

So I am using YII framework, I understand that I should turn on debugging on, so in [project-name]/index.php file in the top I pasted code.

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

But it didin't work for me, still can't see any changes.

I also try ctrl+f5 on page refresh.

Maybe I should look in to Apache configuration?

If some one know please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);` causes a debug dump to be sent to the screen when an exception is thrown. Without that code there will be a single line exception error.